# Do hibernate OGM supports mongodb in sharded environment?

Tags: java, mongodb, sharding, hibernate-ogm

If yes, how do I provide multiple hosts in persistence.xml ?

Can I use it with WiredTiger storage engine?

Does it support mongodb 3.0 drivers?

Comment: did you manage to find the answer? I am seeking for the same information.

Comment: @ObaidMaroof If you see [release note](http://in.relation.to/2015/06/02/hibernate-ogm-42-final-is-out/) its there, in Whats New!!! But I am unable to find documentation. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharded collections are not supported yet, see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-620

Since version 4.2 it uses MongoDB 3 drivers.

Comment: What about 5th point [here](http://in.relation.to/2015/06/02/hibernate-ogm-42-final-is-out#H-WhatsNew). Are they lying?